# Add a line to a JSON file using CLI in specific location

Tags: json, linux, string, replace, insert

I have a JSON file where I need to insert a new line in between two existing lines.

The original line looks like:

```
"item23": {
    "item23Config": [
```

I need to add an additional line so that it looks like this:

```
 "item23": {
    "item23variable": "$variable",
    "item23Config": [
```

From what I understand, this should be relatively easy with jq - but most of the solutions I've read for adding a new line are talking about appending the data onto the end of the JSON file, rather than looking for a specific line and inserting it afterwards.

There's also a possibility I may have to do this with sed (to avoid installing any additional packages).

If this was Powershell, I'd simply do a find and replace for the whole section (dirty, but it works) - However, I'm rather rusty these days on Linux.

Comment: " find and replace for the whole section (dirty, but it works)" you could do this with `sed` if  `"item23Config"` is a unique string.  "I need to insert a new line in between two existing lines."  it really shouldn't matter where the new key/value pair goes as long as it's in the same section.

Comment: Instead of being so complicated .. You could just use `jq`

Comment: See the answer in the linked question. If you really need the new property at the beginning, use `|=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you kindly- didn't know about the += which is why I couldn't find the answer when using Google-Fu Got what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Google "jq add property to object" finds it.